# How can I make a bounding box better fit a sprite?

Tags: 2d, sprites, bounding-boxes

I'm working on a simple 2D platformer for learning purposes and I'm trying to add a bounding box to the player sprite.

I've managed to get it working; however, I'm having difficulty with sizing it to fit around the sprite better.

I have two versions of my code: the old version that doesn't change the size of the bounding box and the new version that does. The problem with the new code is I had to add a bunch of things that I feel are unnecessary such as an offset variable and getter functions to the Rectangle class to get the X and Y value since I needed to update my player code to use the bounding box position instead of the sprite (not entirely sure if this is bad or good).

Old Version

```
Sprite::Sprite(Graphics& graphics, const std::string& filePath, int sourceX, int sourceY, int width, int height,
    float posX, float posY) :
    x(posX),
    y(posY)
{
    this->boundingBox = Rectangle(this->x, this->y, width * globals::SPRITE_SCALE, height * globals::SPRITE_SCALE);
}

void Sprite::draw(Graphics& graphics, int x, int y) {
    SDL_Rect destinationRectangle = { x, y, this->sourceRect.w * globals::SPRITE_SCALE, this->sourceRect.h * globals::SPRITE_SCALE };
    graphics.blitSurface(this->spriteSheet, &this->sourceRect, &destinationRectangle);
}

void Sprite::update() {
    this->boundingBox = Rectangle(this->x, this->y, this->sourceRect.w * globals::SPRITE_SCALE, this->sourceRect.h * globals::SPRITE_SCALE);
}
```

[image: Old code result]

New Code

```
const int leftOffset = 9 * globals::SPRITE_SCALE;
const int rightOffset = 7 * globals::SPRITE_SCALE;
const int topOffset = 10 * globals::SPRITE_SCALE;
const int bottomOffset = 0 * globals::SPRITE_SCALE;

Sprite::Sprite(Graphics& graphics, const std::string& filePath, int sourceX, int sourceY, int width, int height,
    float posX, float posY) :
    x(posX),
    y(posY)
{
    this->boundingBox = Rectangle(this->x + leftOffset, this->y + topOffset,
        (width * globals::SPRITE_SCALE) - (leftOffset + rightOffset),
        (height * globals::SPRITE_SCALE) - (topOffset + bottomOffset));
}

void Sprite::draw(Graphics& graphics, int x, int y) {
    SDL_Rect destinationRectangle = { x, y, this->sourceRect.w * globals::SPRITE_SCALE, this->sourceRect.h * globals::SPRITE_SCALE };
    graphics.blitSurface(this->spriteSheet, &this->sourceRect, &destinationRectangle);
}

void Sprite::update() {
    this->boundingBox = Rectangle(this->x + leftOffset, this->y + topOffset,
        (this->sourceRect.w * globals::SPRITE_SCALE) - (leftOffset + rightOffset),
        (this->sourceRect.h * globals::SPRITE_SCALE) - (topOffset + bottomOffset));
}
```

[image: New code result]

Comment: It's not clear to me what specific problem you need help solving here. Is the "new" code giving you the bounding box you want, or do you want it to be different in some way? Is there a specific issue in the code that you'd like advice about how to improve?

Comment: @DMGregory I’m trying to see what I can do better (if anything). The new code allows me to fit the bounding box around the sprite better which I don’t think was possible in the old code, however, I’m most likely going to need offset values for everything now and I don’t know where I’d keep that, but this just seems like a not so good idea. Also, the bounding box and sprite position being available to the player confuses me since I don’t know what should be considered the players position.

Comment: What makes an offset not seem like a good idea? If it's necessary to support the outcome you want, then it sounds like a sensible inclusion. "Should" for what purpose? Remember, there's no external arbiter who decides what the "right" thing to do in a game is — it's all just a matter of what serves the gameplay you want. What specific code making use of the player's position are you having trouble adapting, how do you want it to behave, and how does that differ from what you have?